# How do I verify that a specific constructor of a given class is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng, jmockit

Suppose the following is the class under test:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "someFile.txt" );
        // .. do something about fis
    }
}
```

How do I verify that the constructor `FileInputStream( String )` is called when the method `doSomething()` is invoked with a parameter `"someFile.txt"` using jMockit?

I'm not looking for an answer that is manual or not automated. I'm looking for an answer that employs automated unit-testing using tools such as JUnit or TestNG with the help of mocking and spying tools preferably jMockit.

Comment: if the constructor is not invoked correctly, you should get some exception when invoking any methods in `fis`

Comment: What do you mean by 'verify'?

Comment: @SajanChandran, not getting an exception does not necessarily mean it has successfully called a specific constructor. For example, it could have done nothing instead.

Comment: Can't you just use a `System.out.println("It works!");` to see if it's called?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be checking that the class fulfils its contract? Is its contract to call a specific class's specific constructor? Isn't that an implementation detail? In modern Java this should probably be replaced by calling methods from `Paths` and `Files`. If the class is improved to do that, do you want your test to fail?

Comment: @RealSkeptic "Is its contract to call a specific class's specific constructor?" Yes. The contract says it should read from a filesystem, and one way to test that is to verify that `FileInputStream` constructor is called with specific parameter. Of course this question is oversimplified for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Then your contract is *not* that the constructor is called. The contract is to check that a read from the filesystem occurred. The class can legitimately call `Files.newInputStream( Paths.get("somefile.txt") )` and achieve the requirement.

Comment: @RickvanOsta, I'm not sure if you have a background on automated unit-testing. But don't you think I wouldn't be posting here if I could simply do that?

Comment: The following definitely does not answer your question, but... what are you trying to test? If you want to test whether your file is read, why not simply check your program knows what that file content is (e.g correctly extracted and inserted in DB or whatever you want)?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I could do that. That will require to verify a call to static method `newInputStream( ..)`. But the question is about verifying a constructor call and not about verifying a call to a static method. I just gave that as an example.

Comment: @AndreiI, that is no longer unit-testing but more of a functional testing. The question is **not** really about verifying what the code does like if it reads from a file but **verifying that a call to constructor has been made**. That's the focus of the question. I just made that up as an example. In unit-testing, you verify the interaction between objects or classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the JMockit Expectations API, a test can verify constructor invocations just like method invocations. The test just needs to specify the class as `@Mocked`. For example:

```
@Test
public void exampleTestThatVerifiesConstructorCall(@Mocked FileInputStream anyFIS)
{
    new MyClass().doSomething();

    new Verifications() {{ new FileInputStream("someFile.txt"); }};
}
```

That said, I would recommend to avoid mocking low-level classes like `FileInputStream`, which usually are just internal implementation details of the class under test. A better test would use an actual file and check somehow that it was read as expected.

Comment: +1. The method actually returns an InputStream. The contract says it should check first from the classpath, if not found, then check in the filesystem. So it's actually like `InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( url ); if( is == null ) { is = new FileInputStream( url ); } return is;` I haven't thought about a better way of testing that than verifying a constructor call to FIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMockit's `$init` for verifying constructor calls:

```
@Test
void testDoSomethingCallsConstructorWithStringArgument throws FileNotFoundException() {
    new MockUp<FileInputStream>() {
        @Mock(invocations = 1) // Verifies one call
        void $init(String file) {
            assertEquals("someFile.txt", file);
        }
    };

    // TODO Setup an object of MyClass
    myObject.doSomething();
}
```

(Unfortunately I can't test this at the moment)